# Why do most Azure naming conventions include the resource type in the name?

Tags: azure, naming-conventions

Most naming conventions for Azure put resource types and other metadata in the resource name.

For me, this feels like a lot of unnecessary duplication, and leads to hard to read cryptic names full of abbreviations.

Most of the views or tools I use already show important metadata like resource type, location or resource group. For example, the "All resources" view has a column for the type and there is also a type specific icon right next to the resource name. Adding the type to the name feels like unnecessary duplication and makes the names harder to read.

We also try to manage our resources 100% via infrastructure as code. In terraform, when I specify a resource, I already have to include the type (for example "azurerm_storage_account.my_account_name").

When I work with the cli commands, they also include the type ("az storage ...", "az vm ...").

So what am I missing? What's the benefit of putting the type in the name?

The same goes for other metadata. Why duplicate things in the name that I already define as tags? If I want to see team name or application for example, then I define them as tag and add them as column to my resources view. Thats way easier to read then from the middle of some cryptic long resource name.

Is there actually a really good reason to also duplicate all these information in the resource name, or does everybody do it just because Microsoft recommends it? Wouldn't it make more sense to put all those metadata in tags and have a well defined tagging strategy?

[image: example resource list]

Comment: The reason why most Azure naming conventions include the resource type in the name is to provide consistency, prevent naming clashes, and allow administrators to quickly locate and manage resources. Check this out- -   [Develop your naming and tagging strategy for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/naming-and-tagging#develop-your-naming-and-tagging-strategy-for-azure-resources)

Comment: -   [Naming overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/govern/resource-consistency/naming#naming-overview)
-   [Organize your Azure resources effectively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-setup-guide/organize-resources#naming-standards)

Comment: Thanks @arko. However, as you can see in the screenshot, all these information are already provided in separate columns or I can add them as tags. I don't see the additional value of repeating them in the resource name. 

Are there any important places that I did not think about yet which don't show these other fields, but only the resource name?

Comment: True, as you have pointed out, most views and tools already show important metadata like resource type, location, or resource group. Adding the type to the name can feel like unnecessary duplication and make the names harder to read. It may make more sense to put all metadata in tags and have a well-defined tagging strategy.